# SISO system identification

Tags: matlab, controls, system-identification

I have a datasheet (around 100 samples) where for a real SISO system (DC motor), I know the input and output. With `tfest` command, I can form first order to nth order transfer function using the same data (loaded with `iddata` function) for the system.

But in real life the system can be either 1st order or nth order.

Like in MATLAB, using same `iddat` (contains the sample values), I can generate following transfer functions:

```
sys1 = tfest(iddat, 1, 1, 0.5); %number of zero=1, pole=1, 1st order system

sys1 =

  From input "u1" to output "y1":
       exp(-0.5*s) * (2.932 s - 0.1862) / (s + 1.082)
```

---

```
sys = tfest(iddat, 3, 2, 0.5);%number of zero=3, pole=2, 2nd order system 

sys =

  From input "u1" to output "y1":
       exp(-0.5*s) * (0.1936 s^2 - 0.02193 s + 0.0006905) / ( s^3 + 0.07175 s^2 + 0.05526 s + 1.772e-13)
```

Can someone explain the scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fitting a model to an experimental data requires a minimum amount of knowledge about the underlying physical system.

Here you have a DC motor which probably does not have any zeros and no DC gain but you are forcing matlab to fit a proper 3rd order transfer function and it is giving you the closest one (not necessarily the correct one).

Instead remove the half a second delay and let the function find the time constant for you. So

```
tfest(iddat,1);
```

would be sufficient (or try with 3 if you are suspicious about the motor drive).